# Latest ember.js (1.0.0.0) does not recognize "find" and "createRecord"

Tags: ember.js

I just upgraded to the latest ember.js. Right after that, my app started to fail.

Here is the Firebug output:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.0.0
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.2
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.0.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2
DEBUG: -------------------------------

Attempting URL transition to /
Transition #1: Beginning validation for transition to clocks.index
Transition #1: application: calling beforeModel hook
Transition #1: application: resolving model
Transition #1: application: calling afterModel hook
Transition #1: application: validation succeeded, proceeding
Transition #1: clocks: calling beforeModel hook
Transition #1: clocks: resolving model
Transition #1: clocks.index: transition was aborted
Transition #1: clocks: handling error: TypeError: App.Clock.find is not a function
Error while loading route:
TypeError: App.Clock.find is not a function 
    return App.Clock.find();
TypeError: App.Clock.find is not a function 
    return App.Clock.find();
TypeError: App.Clock.createRecord is not a function
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
App.ClocksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var locationService = UtilitiesHelper.LocationService.getInstance();
    locationService.getLocation(function(location) {
            App.Clock.createRecord({
                city: location.city,
                country: location.country,
                latitude: location.latitude,
                longitude: location.longitude,
                color: '#483D8B',
                order: -10
            });
        });

        return App.Clock.find();
    }
});
```

I am not able to figure out what has changed in the new version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the latest versions of Ember Data (Beta 2 and later) instead of `App.Clock.find()` you will have to do `this.get('store').find('clock')`.

Please have read through the [Ember Data Beta Transition documentation](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md). `find` is covered in the very first section.

You will also need to update your `createRecord` to:

```
  this.get('store').createRecord('clock', {
     city: location.city,
     country: location.country,
     latitude: location.latitude,
     longitude: location.longitude,
     color: '#483D8B',
     order: -10
  });
```

Though these are likely not the only changes you'll need to make to migrate your code to the recent versions. This [post](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/migrating-from-ember-data-0-13-to-1-0-0-beta-1-my-findings/2368) might also be helpful.